# Nav links in fixed flex header get cut off page when window is resized

Tags: html, css, flexbox, header, nav

Ideally I want to keep the same layout when the browser window shrinks. I don't know if I need media queries to do that. I was trying to use flex-shrink but it wasn't having any effect. I thought flex has a default shrink property? I think part of the problem is I have too many css rules that may be conflicting with one another- I'm trying to get it to look like the wireframe image (below). Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/a1d3nmam3d0v/pen/YzEBoWb).

wireframe-
[image: header wireframe]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: unset;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  background-color: white;
  height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 24px;
  align-items: center;
  display: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.logo {
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  height: 50px;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-family: 'Cantarell', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: gray;
}

.logo .bold {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
}

nav {
  margin-right: 24px;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Cantarell', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Colmar Academy</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cantarell:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images\ic-logo-white.svg" />
  <link href="reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="images\ic-logo.svg" alt="logo" />
      <h1><span class="bold">Colmar</span>Academy</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">On campus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">For companies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set media queries for your elements to adjust their size at a certain browser width. See the sample ones I added below:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .bold,
  .logo > h1,
  nav > ul > li > a {
    font-size: smaller;
    white-space: nowrap;
  } 
  .logo {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Of course, feel free to change the sizing as you desire. See it working in the snippet below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: unset;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  background-color: white;
  height: 64px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 24px;
  align-items: center;
  display: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.logo {
  height: 32px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  height: 50px;
}

.logo h1 {
  font-family: "Cantarell", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: gray;
}

.logo .bold {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
}

nav {
  margin-right: 24px;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  margin-left: 16px;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Cantarell", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  .bold,
  .logo > h1,
  nav > ul > li > a {
    font-size: smaller;
    white-space: nowrap;
  } 
  .logo {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Colmar Academy</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cantarell:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images\ic-logo-white.svg" />
  <link href="reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src='https://svgshare.com/i/esC.svg' title='' />
      <h1><span class="bold">Colmar</span>Academy</h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">On campus</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">For companies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still messing with the numbers, like you said, to find the right fit but this'll work